# Can`t drag @IBOutlet from swift file to storyboard ViewController in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I use Xcode 7.2

**I can use Control+drag to swift file to create a @IBOutlet**
[image]

**But I can't drag @IBOutlet in swift file to storyboard.** Here I don't use any other key, just drag.
[image]Actually when I moving mouse to the spot before @IBOutlet, nothing happened and when I trying to drag it a breakpoint added.

1.I`m sure I use the right Class name
2.My project is not in a strange path or name

Comment: I am also using Xcode 7.2, it works for me, Can you add screenshot while trying ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same problem all of a sudden. I reinstalled Xcode but still did not work. I'm getting desperate about this.

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274919/39402. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

don't use Control, only drag with mouse from circle icons.You can see in the picture below. Circle icons in red box

[image]

Comment: That`s my problem. When I move mouse to the circle icons, nothing happen and when I drag it there will add a breakpoint.

Comment: you didn't use "Ctrl" key. Did you mean?

Comment: Yes. In swift file I don`t use Control key

Comment: for example 
for this outlet : @IBOutlet weak var Background1: UIImageView! drag to UIImageView object 
Did you like this?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes I want code the IBOutlet and drag to storyboard.

Comment: it's weird.Did you try on another project?

Comment: Yes, I create a new one, and open my old project which is created some month ago and they all like this. The old project used Xcode6 which drag worked.

Comment: Rick, please see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274919/39402. It worked for me (as I mentioned above also)

Answer (score 2):

### Changed Behavior

The behavior has changed in new versions of Xcode (I'm not certain but it might have been since 7+.). Older versions of the product might still have the gutter shortcut working.

Now you have to either open the Connections Inspector or right-click on the view controller in the Document Outline. Once open, drag from the defined IBOutlet to your UIView subclass (UIButton, UITextField, etc...)

### Connections Inspector

[image: inspector]

### Controller View

[image: controller]

### Official Guidance

Search your local help for: Interface Builder Connections Help: Creating an Outlet Connection. You will find these are the only methods that now work. The gutter shortcut does not work.

[image: apple-help]

**Nota Bene:**

> You can confirm this behavior and other changes to Xcode shortcuts by
>   choosing the following menu **Help > Xcode Overview** and
>   taking a look at *Part V: Building a User Interface*, section *Connecting Objects In Code*.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the following solved the issue: The IBOutlet's ViewController class file cannot connect to the Main.storyboard file because the name of the ViewController class was renamed instead of refactored. Try refactoring names to make changes everywhere in the file instead of just renaming the names in the file. Otherwise xml tags of Main.storyboard will still contain the old values. This is why it fails to establish a connection between the two files when dragging the IBOutlet's circle icons to the respective UIElement in the Main.storyboard file.