# XCode - can't make a connection from storyboard to code

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I ctrl-drag an object from the storyboard to code in the assistant editor I get this error:

[image]

I've googled the hell out of this problem and tried every suggestion that I could find. I restarted XCode, restarted my computer, updated XCode, deleted and re-added files, etc. and nothing is working. I saw suggestions to manually write the code and then drag from the circle in the gutter to the object I want to connect to in the storyboard. This would be a fine solution, but for some reason the outlet isn't showing up.

Normally the outlet would be to the left of the line number in the gutter

[image]

I am not sure what to do at this point except cry. If anyone has any suggestions or help to offer that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are dragging the IBOutlets to proper viewController owner class ???? Check if ViewController is set properly or not in Xcode, check if Assistant editor is in automatic or manual mode

Comment: Yes, I have triple checked that I am connecting to the proper class. If it is not the proper class, it doesn't even let me drag into the code. Assistant editor returns no results in automatic mode - does that mean anything? I have to find the class in manual mode.

Comment: Delete the derived data folder of Xcode, restart the Xcode, it happens sometimes with new Xcode

Comment: send us your project.

Comment: deleting the derived data folder didn't fix the problem. also, this is a problem on every single xcode project on my computer, even very old ones. how do i send a file?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with XCode installation.

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: ah i fixed the problem! for anyone else with this issue, needed to turn on indexing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959709/stopping-xcode-from-indexing

Comment: [Workaround can be found here:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40933262/1457385)