# Why can't I create an IBAction connection in Xcode?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I've been doing this task for a long time and today I started having a problem, I can not create an IBAction, I've tried everything.

[image: I just can see the outlet and the collection, why can't see the action?]

I just can see the outlet and the collection, why can't see the action?

Comment: You probably didn't put right class in your ViewController, that's why Interface Builder doesn't allow you to create outlets.

Comment: @NSDmitry, he would not even be able to drag the outlet, it the problem would be that, like your suggesting.

Comment: @Tayo i had this problem as well, it is Xcode bug. Restart, clean project, remove derived data, etc.. If it would not work, you can still try to declare your propery manually, and connect the declared property with the element in IB.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40933262/1457385

Comment: @dirtydanee Thanks for everything, but I've tried all this before, I've been reading in many places and I can not find anything. The rarest thing is that in other projects I can do it but in this not : S