# The missing Outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c

I define two outlets on ViewController.

```
// ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@end
```

But they are missing When I check this two Outlets on storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Click on `View Controller` (3 lines above). The outlet is *declared* in the view controller but not *connected* by default.

Comment: When you create an IBOutlet in the UIViewController, XCode does not create it automatically in the Storyboard.

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932172/unable-to-connect-iboutlet-from-storyboard-to-uiview-subclass

Comment: I think question is confusing, Can you please clear what actually you want? **1.** Your `Outlets` doesn't display in `Connections Inspector` (Follow comment by @vadian) or **2.** You expect that when you write `Outlet` line in your `ViewController` then it automatically connected in storyBoard? (You have to do it manually)